# pass command-line arguments to runpy

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two files, one which has a side effect I care about that occurs within the `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard:

```py
# a.py
d = {}
if __name__ == "__main__":
    d['arg'] = 'hello'
```

The second file imports the first (using `runpy`) and prints the dictionary:

```py
# b.py
import runpy
m = runpy.run_module('a', run_name='__main__')
print(m['d'])  # {'arg': 'hello'}
```

So far this works.  But now I want to change the first file to accept a command line argument:

```py
import sys
d = {}
if __name__ == "__main__":
    d['arg'] = process(sys.argv[1])
```

The problem is that `process()` is written by someone else and outside of my control, but I still want to get the updated dictionary `d` after it has been "processed".

How can I mock `sys.argv` before calling `runpy`, or otherwise provide that value to `a.py`?

Comment: What's `process`?

Comment: `process` is arbitrary code made by the author of `a.py`, outside of my control.  It might not be a function, it could be a bunch of statements.  The point is that `sys.argv[1]` is used as an input for further processing before the dictionary is updated.

Comment: `runpy.run_module` doesn't return a dict containing `arg` in the keys. Are you sure the code is working? Or it's just _happening_ to be mocking the argument?

Comment: You're right, I had a typo.  `runpy.run_module` returns a module with the key `d`, so the above should have been `m['d']`.

Comment: @asn-0184 I updated the question in response to your comment, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be this straightforward?  I found this solution almost by accident.

```sh
$ python3 b.py foo
{'arg': 'foo'}
```

It seems that `sys.argv[1]` is passed in to `a` even when `b.py` is called from the command line.

### edit

here is an example session from my shell:

```sh
me@desktop$ cat a.py b.py
import sys
d = {}
filename = sys.argv[1]
if __name__ == "__main__":
    d['result'] = filename + ' world'


# usage:
# python3 b.py filename
# 'filename' is passed in to the a module
import runpy
aa = runpy.run_module('a', run_name='__main__')
print(aa['d'])  # {}

me@desktop$ python3 b.py hello
{'result': 'hello world'}
```

Comment: Maybe this works in the specific context, but what if I want `b.py` to _choose_ the command line arguments to send to `a.py` based on some other logic?

Answer (score 1):

For those who stumbled across this post like me, you can just pass the command line arguments directly. As an example, if I have

```py
# a.py
import argparse

def parse_args():
    # fmt: off
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--myvar")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    # fmt: on
    return args

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parse_args()
    print(args.myvar)
```

```py
# b.py

import runpy
runpy.run_path(path_name='a.py', run_name="__main__")
```

I get

```sh
$ python a.py 
None
$ python a.py --myvar test
test
$ python b.py 
None
$ python b.py --myvar test
test
```