# Passing command line arguments to runpy

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I pass command line arge to runpy.

I.e. if I can do `python3 -m foo --arg1=abc`

how can I add `--arg1=abc` as `sys.argv[1]` when launching the process like:

```
import runpy
runpy.run_module('foo')
```

Note, a question on this subject exists here: [pass command-line arguments to runpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756213/pass-command-line-arguments-to-runpy) bu the author was trying to do something else and it was never answered.

Comment: ***How do I pass command line arge to runpy.***: Why do you think, you have to do so? `foo` can read `sys.argv` by default.

Answer (score -3):

Use standard python library: [argrparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

For sake of example I've static coded runpy class

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser as ArgParser

class runpy:
    @staticmethod
    def run_module(arg):
        print(arg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    description = (
            'runpy commandline args')
    parser = ArgParser(description=description)
    parser.add_argument('--arg1', default="foo", type=str,
                            help='help text')
    options = parser.parse_args()
    runpy.run_module(options.arg1)
```